# Why is IIS7 blocked from accessing my database when connecting to a website via a browser from a client machine?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7

When I access the website from the same machine IIS is running on I am able to connect to the database, but not if I try to access it remotely. The only way I've managed to get it to connect is when I specify Physical Path Credentials:

[click to open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTtBO.png)

This doesn't work for me because, I am using the username as a search criteria when querying the database and this way I always get the same username (the one I specified in the physical path credentials).

I am confused because, when accessing the website locally and remotely I use the same credentials and I get different results.

This is the exception that is thrown when trying to access the site remotely:

> ByNadexLoginSystem.Exception: System.Exception:
>   'SelectDataObject()' failed --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server) --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace

I have tried adding folder permissions as pointed out here:
[ASP.NET Application page not working on clients computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155763/asp-net-application-page-not-working-on-clients-computers/2156306#2156306) with no success whatsoever.

The SQL server is configured to allow remote connections.

I am sure it is a permissions problem I just can't find where. Any ideas?

Comment: Which user is IIS using to connect to SQL Server?

Comment: I am using impersonation so the user IIS should be using to connect to the SQL Server depends on who is accessing the intranet site. I am using to same user credentials to log in on the machine IIS is running and when accessing the website from another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, I want to give credit to [Sean Lange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3813116/sean-lange). Thanks to his question it gave me a line of investigation to follow. While going through msdns documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx I found this:

> If SQL Server is on a different computer than the Web server, the
>   Windows identity must be able to flow across the network to the remote
>   instance of SQL Server. (Windows networks that have been configured
>   appropriately with Kerberos authentication are able to do this.)
>   However, depending on the settings in the identity configuration
>   element, the Windows identity established on the operating system
>   thread for ASP.NET applications may not be able to flow properly to
>   the remote SQL Server.
>
> In IIS, only Basic Authentication logs users on with a security token
>   that flows across the network to a remote SQL server. By default,
>   other IIS security modes used in conjunction with the identity
>   configuration element settings will not result in a token that can
>   authenticate to a remote SQL Server.

Enabling Impersonation and Basic Authentication ( disabled Windows Authentication ) solved it!